# Loading component in React not displaying while page is loading

Tags: reactjs, loading

I have a page that displays media from an API and created a Loading component to show a loading state while the API is loading. I'm able to get the loading component to show on a page that displays 1 item from the API, but on a another page where I'm loading multiple items it does not display. How would I go about creating a loading component for this?

```
    export default function Explore() {
    const [media, setMedia] = useState([]);
    const [faves, setFaves] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const abortController = new AbortController();
        const opts = { signal: abortController.signal };

        fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${apiKey}&count=15`, opts)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => setMedia(data))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
        return () => abortController.abort();
    }, []);

    if (!media) return <Loading />;

    const addFave = (fave) => {
        const isAlreadyStarred = faves.filter(
            item => item === fave
        )

        if (isAlreadyStarred.length > 0) {
            return;
        }
        const newFavesList = [...faves, fave];
        setFaves(newFavesList);
        // saveToLocalStorage(newFavesList);
    };

    const removeFave = (e) => {
        const url = e.target.getAttribute("url")
        setFaves(faves.filter(favorite => favorite.url !== url));
    };

    return (...)
```

Loading component displays when fetching API a different way:

```
export default function Today() {
            const [mediaData, setMediaData] = useState(null);
        
            useEffect(() => {
                fetchMedia();
                async function fetchMedia() {
                    const res = await fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${apiKey}`);
                    const data = await res.json();
                    setMediaData(data);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }, []);
        
            if (!mediaData) return <Loading />;
        
            return (...)
```

Comment: set media initial state to `null` instead of `[ ]`... since its an empty array `!media` will always return false. The empty array still counts and therefore media is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you initialize `media` with `[]` which is a truthy value, so the check `if (!media)` (`![]`) will evaluate to `false`.

You can either initialize `media` with `null`, check `!media.length` or better have a loading state like this:

```js
const [media, setMedia] = useState([])
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)

        const abortController = new AbortController();
        const opts = { signal: abortController.signal };

        fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${apiKey}&count=15`, opts)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => setMedia(data))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error.message))
            .finally(() => setLoading(false));

        return () => abortController.abort();
    }, []);

if (loading) return <Loading />;
```

This way you could also add an empty message:

```js
const [media, setMedia] = useState([])
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)

        const abortController = new AbortController();
        const opts = { signal: abortController.signal };

        fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${apiKey}&count=15`, opts)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => setMedia(data))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error.message))
            .finally(() => setLoading(false));

        return () => abortController.abort();
    }, []);

if (loading) return <Loading />;

if (!media || media.length < 1) return 'No data';
```

Answer (score 1):

`![]` is falsy.  If you change it to something like

```
if (!media.length) return <Loading />;
```

that should work for you